# Adjusting for variables outside of minimal adjustment set for total causal effect in a DAG

Tags: regression, model-selection, dag, causal-diagram

I have a fairly elaborate Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) for the analysis that I am running, but I am presenting a simplified example here to clarify a few things.

Here is a DAG from *dagitty.net*:

[image]

- According to the graph, I only need to adjust for **A** in order to close
  the back door path and to identify the total causal effect of
  **Treatment** on **Outcome**. In other words, the *minimal adjustment set* for
  this diagram is just **A**.
- Conversely, if I were to condition on **C**, the pathway
  **Treatment** -> **C** -> **Outcome** would be biased because **C** is on the front door path between the **Treatment** and the
  **Outcome**, so **C** should be left out from a regression model OR else **B** would also need to be conditioned on to close the formed back door path.

My question is about variables like **B**, the adjustment for which is not strictly necessary (assuming **C** stays unadjusted for). Adjustment/conditioning on **B** or leaving out completely is seemingly inconsequential for the total causal effect of **Treatment** on **Outcome**. In this case, what are the implications, benefits or drawbacks of including **B**-type variables in my regression models? Would I not gain any precision or explanatory power in the model by including it as a control, rather than optionally leaving it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Conversely, if I were to condition on C, the pathway Treatment -> C -> Outcome would be biased because C is on the front door path between the Treatment and the Outcome, so C should be left out from a regression model OR else B would also need to be conditioned on to close the formed back door path.

I don't think this is right. Controlling for `B` would not solve all the problems you would introduce by controlling for `C`. While it would help you close the back-door path `Treatment -> C <- B -> Outcome`, the front-door path `Treatment -> C -> Outcome` would still be closed.

> what are the implications, benefits or drawbacks of including B-type variables in my regression models? Would I not gain any precision or explanatory power in the model by including it as a control, rather than optionally leaving it out?

Yes, that's right. Controlling for `A` allows you to identify the total causal effect of Treatment on Outcome unbiasedly. *Additionally* controlling for `B` should yield a more precise estimator.